# Comparing data from 2 tables and display the result on a dropdownlist using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have the 2 following tables: **Country** and **Postal**
I retrive all the countries in a DropDownAddCountry and i wan't by doing that to display all the postals belonging to the country in another dropdown (DropDownAddPostals).
The country table have a coulmn **CountryID** and postal also have a coulm **CountryID**. So i wan't the result to be based on match between CountryID and CountryID (from both tables):

My code look like this now (and it's not correct):

```
using (DB_Entities tt = new DB_Entities())
{
    var sql = from q1 in tt.Country
    join q2 in tt.Postal on q1.CountryID equals q2.CountryID
    select new { q2.Postal1 };
    if(sql != null)
    {
        DropDownAddPostal= sql.Postal1;
    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Don't use anonymous types (especially if they are not necessary).
You can set the collection to your `DropDownList` with the `DataSource`-Property.

```
using (var tt = new DB_Entities())
{
    var sql =
        from q1 in tt.Country
        join q2 in tt.Postal on q1.CountryID equals q2.CountryID
        select q2.Postal1

    DropDownAddPostal.DataSource = sql.ToList();
    DropDownAddPostal.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jan!
this line here:   DropDownAddPostal(sql.Postal1); 
comes with an error that im trying to use dropdown as a method and it does not work if i make like this also  DropDownAddPostal= sql.Posal1

Comment: The dropdownpostal is a field but used as a method, this is the full error msg stil

Comment: DropDownPostal is a Control, isn't it? If true, which type of Control (WinForms, Web, ...)?

Comment: thanks for the help, it seems that when i debug the code nothing happens, maybe something worng with my dropdownlist